# Sum aggregation is returning null when ran on empty dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions

I am trying to run below query:

```
df.filter(col("id") == id).agg(
            F.sum(col("count")).alias("count")
        )
```

In this above example for the initial run df will be an empty dataframe and hence filter is going to give count as 0. But when sum aggregation runs on it, its giving me result_df of count 1 which looks like this:
+-----------+
|count
+-----------+
|       null|
+-----------+

I want result_df to be of size 0. Can anyone please help in finding out what am I doing wrong?

I have tried changing the data type of "count" column to long as well but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use na.drop: [na.drop example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Here i example similar to yours with added na.drop

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df = spark.createDataFrame(
   [("APPLE", "1"),
   ("APPLE", "2"),
   ("GRAPE", "3"),
   ("BANANA", "4"),
   ("BANANA", "5")],
   ["id", "count"]
)

df.filter(col("id") == F.lit("WRONG_ID_GIVING_EMPTY_DF")).agg(
    F.sum(col("count")).alias("count")
).na.drop().show()
```

Results:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
+-----+
```